# Can we connect two of the same plural nouns with a preposition?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, verbs, nouns, countable-nouns

Are these examples correct?

1. Villages after villages were destroyed by terrorists.
2. City after city was set on fire.
3. Pages after pages were reviewed multiple times.

Comment: 'City' is not a plural noun.

Comment: Perhaps, he wanted to ask if it's correct to say cities after cities were...

Comment: Are you asking about prepositions in general or just the preposition **after**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In none of these examples is it idiomatic to use the plural, neither for the nouns nor the verbs.

One would say ***Village after village was destroyed./ City after city was set on fire./Page after page was reviewed multiple times.***

Comment: Although you might say *drops upon drops of water fell from the roof.* [See Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=drops+upon+drops%2Cdrop+upon+drop&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=5).

Comment: @PeterShor with "upon" the plural works. with "after" it does not. For example, *cities upon cities* makes perfect sense, but "cities after cities" does not.

Comment: @Esther Very good point, I agree.

Comment: This is known in linguistics as the NPN construction. http://muse.jhu.edu/content/crossref/journals/language/v084/84.1jackendoff.pdf